# How change color of titlebar buttons on inactive windows using css?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

So I wrote my own gtk.css in ~/.config/gtk-3.0 to override the installed theme, But now i want to change the color of buttons in inactive windows.

```
button.titlebutton {
  min-height: 16px;
  min-width: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  color: transparent;
}

button.titlebutton.close {
  background-color: @error_color;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button.titlebutton.close:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

button.titlebutton.maximize {
  background-color: green;
}

button.titlebutton.maximize:hover {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: black;
}

button.titlebutton.minimize {
  background-color: @warning_color;
}

button.titlebutton.minimize:hover {
  background-color: #e8e337;
  color: black;
}
```

[Current behaviour (active/ inactive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysyiY.png)

[Behaviuor on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgmSp.png)

How do i modify this code to change color of buttons in inactive windows?

Answer (score 0):

did you find out?
Actually I am looking for the opposite effect, change only the active window close button color (leaving inactive windows unchanged), to differentiate more the active window specially in the dark yaru theme.